# Why do some USB devices work only if connected directly and not via a USB hub? (Windows OS)

Tags: windows, usb, usb-hub

I noticed this mostly with my printer, but also occasionally with some other devices connected via the USB port (e.g., smartphone). If I connect it to a USB hub, it will not get detected at all, but if I connect it directly to the USB ports on my motherboard, then it will get properly discovered. I assume it's not a faulty hub since other USB devices (e.g., USB sticks) work well. I noticed this with more than one USB hub, so I feel like there's some general answer to this question that is not strictly tied to my equipment.

I would also accept any solid explanation of why do some USB ports sometimes work and sometimes not for some devices, as I observe this inconsistency even outside of USB hubs.

Comment: Is your USB hub powered (meaning it has a mains power supply attached) or is it just connected to the USB socket on your machine?

Comment: You need a powered Hub for all to work. I do that and no issues.

Comment: I have had this issue with 2 linux laptops and 4 different, DC-powered Dell hubs. The same USB devices sometimes gets detected, sometimes not, sometimes ceases to be while it was in usage. Usually for me it's all USB devices or none, but at the same time ethernet and external screen connected via hub work as usual...

Comment: Indeed, it seems that it's the cheap non-powered USB hubs causing the issue. I've accepted the actual answer since it was very insightful in general with the additional explanation, but thank you both for the comments. @Joce your issue sounds a bit different than mine, considering I would some devices working and some not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB hubs come in two shapes. Those that have a DC power input, and those that don't (I will refer to them as non-powered from hereon; keep in mind they draw power from the USB port but it is a lot less than if they have additional DC input).

In case the hub has no DC power input, it has to draw all power from the USB ports to power itself and the devices attached.

The non-powered USB hubs are very small and cheap and have no capability of delivering a large amount of electricity, so as such, whenever any device asks for high power, they will simply fail in the negotiations round.

A USB hub that is powered has protection build-in to use the DC power input and direct more power to attached USB devices. As such devices that draw more power will not fail the negotiations round and get properly detected.

When it comes to devices that sometimes do and sometimes don't work, if the USB hub has more than one devices attached and one of them requires quite a bit of power, but within the levels of what the USB hub can give, such as a harddisk or flashdrive, another device connected may exceed the amount of power the USB hub can deliver to its devices as it only has limited power from its USB input too. As such, with a non-powered USB hub, sometimes devices just don't work because it needs more power than it can get.

In rare occasions, the USB device gets just enough power to work but the USB hub is at its very limit and any power spike in the grid may cause the PSU to have a little dip causing the USB hub to suddenly not get enough power which may cause one or more of the attached USB devices to the hub to fail, often going accompanied with the "disconnect" sound in windows, notifying that a device was unplugged.

Even if power is restored directly after, because the USB protocol has disconnected the device from the system, the USB plug has to be reconnected to get the device working again.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you! I have both types of USB hubs, and I did notice the DC power one to be consistent. The explanation also makes sense in the context of USB connection instability issues and different types of devices connected to it.

Comment: *"The non-powered USB hubs ..."* -- All USB hubs (and devices/gadgets) require electrical power.  The power can be supplied by an *external* power supply or the power from the host over the bus can be used (i.e. *host* or *bus powered* rather than *"non-powered"*).  The USB hub itself is a USB device.

Comment: @sawdust I thought my answer was clear enough, but added a paragraph for your convenience.

Comment: Also note that there are USB1/2 hubs vs. switches. It also makes sense to buy an USB3 switch (without external power source) because USB3 supplies more power.

Comment: @sawdust What you call "USB hub" is not always a device. That is why I distinguish between USB hubs and switches.

Comment: This is a good answer in a general sense, but OP's question was about a printer, and printers are self-powered so do not draw power from the hub. There are other reasons why some devices fail to function properly through hubs, even powered ones, and it tends to be hard to diagnose and probably due to differences in interpretation of or adherence to various USB specs on the part of either devices or hub firmwares